# Mysql error code Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 4 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I'm new to this forum and if I'm not doing anything according the rules, please tell me.

I'm getting the following error: `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 4 column(s)`

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Vino
(
    idVino            INT(32) NOT NULL,
    marca              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    anio               INT(32) NOT NULL,
    denominacion       VARCHAR(100),
    graduacion         FLOAT NOT NULL,
    viniedo            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cantidad           INT(32) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    idProductor       INT(32) NOT NULL,
    comunidad          VARCHAR(50),
    stock              INT(32) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(comunidad) (
    PARTITION localidad1 VALUES IN ('Madrid', 'Castilla-León','Castilla-La Mancha','Aragón','La Rioja'),
    PARTITION localidad2 VALUES IN ('Cataluña','Baleares','País Valenciano','Murcia'),
    PARTITION localidad3 VALUES IN ('Galicia','Asturias','Cantabria','País Vasco','Navarra'),
    PARTITION localidad4 VALUES IN ('Andalucía','Extremadura','Canarias','Ceuta','Melilla')
);


CREATE TABLE Productor
(
    idProductor  INT(32) NOT NULL,
    DNI           VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    nombre        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    direccion     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);



INSERT INTO Vino(idVino, marca, anio, denominacion, graduacion, viniedo, cantidad, idProductor, comunidad, stock) 
VALUES(1, 'Vega Sicilia', 1998, 'Ribera del Duero', 12.5, 'Castillo Blanco', 200, 1, 'Castilla-León', 200);
```

The table gets produced just fine, but I get the error when I'm executing the code for the values. I've been starring at this for a few hours now and I cant find whats causing it, could anyone help me?

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2bb5aaef80b0d919132f20ed7133e44c)

Comment: which is the SQL statement causing this error? What is the full error statement that includes where in the statement it fails?